# Irreducible representation and observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, observables

Can any one explain why all observables can be associated with irreducible representation? I do not understand what is the relation between these two.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why do all fields in a QFT transform like *irreducible* representations of some group?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498124/2451)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is *a priori* no relation between observables and irreducible representations: an observable is just an observable, and it can connect states in different representations of a group.  An example would be the $\hat z$-component of the dipole moment, which can connect states of different angular momentum.  The radial position $r$ is also a observable, and it can connect states of different energies.

It is often the cases that a *collection* of observable transform irreducibly under a group.  The three components of the dipole moment transform under rotation as angular momentum $L=1$ operators.  In terms of commutation relations, the components of the dipole operators are linear combinations of operators $T^{1}_m\sim r Y^1_m(\theta,\phi)$ with commutation relations
\begin{align}
[\hat L_\pm, T^1_m]=\sqrt{(1\mp m)(2\pm m)}T^1_{m\pm 1}\, ,\qquad 
[\hat L_z,T^1_m]=mT^1_m\, .
\end{align}
The quadrupole moments are a set of operators transforming irreducibly under rotation, this time as $L=2$ operators.

In a finite dimensional space, any observable can be expanded in terms of irreducible tensor operators.  For instance, acting on states of total spion $S$, the operator $S_z$ is proportional to 
\begin{align}
S_z\propto \sqrt{\frac{3}{2S+1}} \sum_{m}  C^{Sm}_{Sm;10}\vert Sm\rangle \langle Sm\vert\, ,
\end{align}
where $C^{Sm'}_{Sm;LM}$ is a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.

More generally, one can show that any operator of the type $\vert a\rangle\langle b\vert$ can be expanded in terms of tensor operators, so that any observable acting on states of total spin $S$ built as (Hermitian) combination of the type
\begin{align}
\sum_{ab} c_{ab} \vert a\rangle\langle b\vert &=\sum_{LM} t_{LM}T^{L}_M \qquad \hbox{where}\\
T^{L}_M&= \sqrt{\frac{2L+1}{2S+1}}\sum_{mm'} C^{Sm'}_{Sm;LM}\vert Sm'\rangle
\langle Sm\vert\, . \tag{1}
\end{align}
The expansion coefficients $t_{LM}$ can be found using the trace orthogonality of the tensors defined in Eq.(1).
Details can be found in multiple sources, such as

> Varshalovich, Dmitriĭ Aleksandrovich, Anatolï Nikolaevitch Moskalev, and Valerii Kel'manovich Khersonskii. Quantum theory of angular momentum. 1988,

or (for a less complete but more focused treatment)

> Klimov, Andrei B., and Sergei M. Chumakov. A group-theoretical approach to quantum optics: models of atom-field interactions. John Wiley & Sons, 2009.

In this case, the matrix elements of the components of a tensor operators are related through the Wigner-Eckart theorem:
\begin{align}
\langle \alpha \ell ' m'\vert T^L_M \vert\beta \ell m\rangle 
= \frac{\langle \alpha \ell '\Vert T^L \Vert\beta \ell \rangle}{\sqrt{2\ell'+1}}
C^{\ell' m'}_{LM;\ell m}  \tag{2}
\end{align}
where the last factor is a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient, and where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are whatever other labels are needed to fully label the initial and final states. The reduced matrix element 
$\langle \alpha \ell '\Vert T^L \Vert\beta \ell \rangle$ is the same for all the components of the tensor.

Eq.(2) states that the ratio of matrix elements of tensor operators between given initial and final states is just a ratio of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.  The selection rules are deduced either from the possible non-zero CGs or from the possible non-zero balues of the reduced matrix element.

The Wigner-Eckart theorem is not limited to angular momentum and associated tensor operators, but in fact can be formulated [quite generally](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401013/36194).

Comment: What do you mean by "it can connect states in different representations of a group"?

Comment: If the group is the group of rotation so states with the same angular momentum span one representation, then the matrix elements of the observable can be non-zero between states with different values of angular momentum.

Comment: Can you suggest me any textbook which has touched upon this topic?

Comment: More on tensor operator and representation of tensor operator. Thank you for answering the question, though i am feeling a bit difficult to understand

Comment: There is a discussion (very limited form) of tensor operators in the newest edition of Griffiths QM.  Also a good intro is in the textbook "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics" by Gordon Baym